TCL regexp ignoring lazy modifier
Desire to extract 'D1P5' from string via TCL regexp.
regexp {\S+_(D\S+?)_} "abc_D1P5_efg_hij_k" dmy var

Undesired output is greedy
puts $var
D1P5_efg_hij

Desired output
D1P5

How to do that?
Version
puts $tcl_patchLevel
8.6.4


Yes, it is common thing with TCL regex. The first one sets the greediness. So, make the first one lazy, too. Or, exclude the _ from \S: \S+_(D[^\s_]+)

Technically, it's the first quantified in the sub-RE that sets the evaluation strategy... but I find that hard to understand as I don't think like the RE engine.

Yeah, by "The first one sets the greediness", I meant to say "The first quantifier sets the greediness"
